# Calculate angle between an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4} = 1 $ and circle $x^2+2x+y^2-4 = 0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Recently I found an interesting exercise in my book that I can't solve and there's not a step-by-step solution for it in my book.

Calculate angle between an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4} = 1 $ and circle $x^2+2x+y^2-4 = 0$ (or more precise, the angle between their tangents).

I've tried everything but can't do anything useful. How do I solve this easily?

Comment: Get the point of intersection (the angle between the tangents us to be calculated for this point, I presume) for the circle and ellipse and write the equations of their tangents. Actually just the slopes. Then apply $\tan \theta= \frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2} $

Comment: Find the points of intersection ellipse and circle  and angle between tangents in this points.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar can you help me with step-by-step solution for this? I can't figure how to get to that part.

Comment: @RedSkyInTheFly Can you obtain their points of intersection?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being too lazy to type it all out. And also for the tiny (and bad) handwriting.[image][image]

Comment: I understand now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Without calculations: the circle has its center at $O=(-1,0)$ and intersects the ellipse at the endpoints of the minor axis, $T=(0,\pm2)$. At $T$ the ellipse has horizontal tangent and the slope of radii $OT$ are $\pm2$. Hence the slope of the tangent is $\mp1/2$, which is also the tangent of the requested angle.